# What's wrong with this simple coffeescript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@response[:domain]) > div.queries > #<%= dom_id(@response[:tag]) %>').fadeOut ->
  $(this).remove()
```

It produces the following error in the logs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (compile error
app/views/domains/untag.js.coffee:2: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
  $(this).remove()
   ^
app/views/domains/untag.js.coffee:3: unterminated string meets end of file
app/views/domains/untag.js.coffee:3: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND):
    1: $('#<%= dom_id(@response[:domain]) > div.queries > #<%= dom_id(@response[:tag]) %>').fadeOut ->
    2:  $(this).remove()
  app/views/domains/untag.js.coffee:3:in `compile'
  app/controllers/domains_controller.rb:45:in `untag'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem (at least, one of them) is in your string

```
'#<%= dom_id(@response[:domain]) > div.queries > #<%= dom_id(@response[:tag]) %>'
```

You open two `<%=` blocks, but close only one.

Comment: Thanks sergio it seems all my problems have been related to syntax errors like this

Answer (score 0):

Weird, it compiles for me. What settings are you using to compile?

[CoffeeScript Test Reference Link](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%24%28%27#%3C%25=%20dom_id%28@response%5B%3adomain%5D%29%20%3E%20div.queries%20%3E%20#%3C%25=%20dom_id%28@response%5B%3atag%5D%29%20%25%3E%27%29.fadeOut%20-%3E%0A%09%24%28this%29.remove%28%29)